# Higher homology groups relative a lower dimensional subspace

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

One often works with reduced homology, which (in the case of say, smplicial homology) is defined as the homology relative a point. Now at every grade except zero, the reduced homology objects are isomorphic to the original ones.

Intuitively, I think this is because a point is $0$-dimensional, so it can only interfere with $0$-cycles. Now suppose I'm looking at the relative homology objects $H_n(X,A)$. Suppose $A$ is a $k$-dimensional manifold in the space $X$. The same intuition temps me to assert that for all $n>k$ $$H_n(X,A)\cong H_n(X)$$
Is this true? How can I prove it? Can this be somehow generalized to topological dimension?

Comment: This is false. Take $X = S^2, A=S^1$. It's probably hopeless unless $n>k+1$. Think about cellular homology.

Comment: @MikeMiller thank you! Indeed what if I ask $n>k+1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative homology is more or less defined so that it fits into a long exact sequence

$$\dots \xrightarrow{\partial} H_n(A) \to H_n(X) \to H_n(X, A) \xrightarrow{\partial} H_{n-1}(A) \to \dots$$

which straightforwardly answers your question: the natural map $H_n(X) \to H_n(X, A)$ is an isomorphism iff it has trivial kernel and full image. By exactness, its kernel is the image of $H_n(A) \to H_n(X)$; a sufficient but not necessary condition for this image to be trivial is that $H_n(A)$ vanishes. By exactness, its image is the kernel of $H_n(X, A) \to H_{n-1}(A)$; again a sufficient but not necessary condition for this kernel to be full is that $H_{n-1}(A)$ vanishes.

So a sufficient but not necessary condition is that $A$ has homological dimension less than $n - 1$. Your intuition should be corrected as follows: the long exact sequence shows that $H_n(A)$ can interfere with both $n$-cycles and $n+1$-cycles, and intuitively this is because on the one hand it can remove some $n$-cycles and on the other hand it can *add* some $n+1$-cycles, roughly because it can cause some $n+1$-chains to become cycles that weren't before.

Comment: As always, thank you for your insightful answer. Where would you recommend to read about homological dimension to gain intuition for the definition?

Comment: By homological dimension I just mean the top dimension in which homology doesn't vanish (and I'm being vague about coefficients: properly it should be with some choice of coefficients, maybe even some choice of local coefficients). For most purposes you can get away with just knowing that $n$-manifolds and $n$-dimensional CW complexes have homological dimension $\le n$.

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant one of [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homological_dimension) definitions. Thanks again!

Comment: @Exterior: the definitions are related; the homological dimension of a space has something to do with the homological dimension of the constant sheaf, in chain complexes of sheaves, although I'm not willing to make precise statements off the top of my head.